# What did people believe to be the cause of the Red Eye?

Tags: noor

In the novella *Noor* by Nnedi Okorafor, the Ultimate Corporation gathers wind energy from the Red Eye, a natural disaster characterized by extremely high winds that of course ultimately turns out to

> have been created by the Ultimate Corporation itself as a direct consequence of the Noor turbines.

How this works is unclear, but it seems that as part of the process of extracting power from the wind, the Noor turbines somehow focus the wind energy from a much larger area into a smaller space, causing tornado-force gales.

People seem to have generally believed that the Red Eye was a type of natural disaster, but of course Earth is not normally home to hurricanes with tornado-force winds that spin up overnight, hover over one spot, and last for years or decades.

As such, what precisely did people think had caused the Red Eye (or what excuse did the Ultimate Corporation spread around)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, people just accept it as being a natural disaster, and don't inquire or speculate into its origin.